# How to fetch particular text from the node in DOM using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, domxpath

Consider an DOM structure of angular based application as Follows,

I need to fetch particular text "disabled" from the above Node. Kindly put your suggestions how I could manage to get that particular text?

I tried for an solution as,

HTML code e.g. `("<div id="button" class="login-link s-btn_primary" disabled>")`

```
 String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='button']").getattribute("innerHTML").trim();
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can first take an element like

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='button']"));
```

and then check if it has the attribute (if it has, assign the required value to a string):

```java
String fetched = 
        element
                .findElements(By.xpath(".[@disabled]"))
                .size() == 1 ? "disabled" : "";
```

The latter code means that you check if the attribute has `disabled` attribute. If yes, you assign `disabled` value to your string, if not, you assign empty value.